# How to intercept application specific MIME types used by 3rd party (Windows) browser/plugins apps?

Tags: url, mime-type

I'm trying to intercept and decipher scripted code that is sent to a previously installed Windows application, after a user have clicked on a particular URL in their web browser which is somehow returning a MIME response that is intercepted by the Win app and processed as a script/program.

The particular example of concern, is how the (Windows) trading application *Think-or-Swim* (aka. TOS) is downloading and running user scripts from either a custom URL handler of the form: `tossc:XXXX` or using a standard URL like `http://tos.mx/A1PZUml` which then sends one of the MIME types:

```
x-scheme-handler/tossc
application/x-tossc
application/x-thinkorswim
```

I have posted a similar question on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66725345/how-to-download-a-script-written-for-thinkorswim-tos-using-curl) but I don't think that forum is appropriate for this question and hope someone here would a have some more technical know-how of how to do this and also explain what's going on. As you can tell I am probably not even using the correct language for asking the question in a clear manner. So feel free to correct me or this post.

Q: **How can I intercept and inspect code that is loaded in this way?**

(Hoping to also learn what is going on and how this is done, or an be done, by e.g. python?)

---

**UPDATE: 2021-04-24**

I managed to get some more info from using *[Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)*.

The settings should be something like this:
[image]

After than you can start ToS by clicking on the link button `View in thinkorswim`. The process table will then be filled and some of the interesting properties are:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\thinkorswim\thinkorswim.exe"  SharedConfigurationLink tossc:A1PZUml

regsvr32.exe /s "C:\Program Files (x86)\thinkorswim\nptossc.dll"
regsvr32.exe /s "C:\Program Files (x86)\thinkorswim\npthinkorswim.dll"
regsvr32.exe /s "C:\Program Files (x86)\thinkorswim\lib32\RTDService.dll"
regsvr32.exe /s "C:\Program Files (x86)\thinkorswim\lib64\RTDService.dll"

C:\Windows\sysnative\reg.exe add HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\tossc /ve /t REG_SZ /d "URL:TOS Sharing Center URL" /f
C:\Windows\sysnative\reg.exe add HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\tossc /v "URL Protocol" /t REG_SZ /f
C:\Windows\sysnative\reg.exe add HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\tossc\shell\open\command /ve /t REG_SZ /d "\"C:\Program Files (x86)\thinkorswim\jre\bin\javaw.exe\" -cp \"C:\Program Files (x86)\thinkorswim\suit\1968.2.0\tos-suit-1968.2.0.jar\" com.devexperts.jnlp.platform.impl.windows.WindowsSharedConfigurationLauncher SharedConfigurationLink %1" /f
C:\Windows\sysnative\reg.exe add HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\thinkorswim /ve /t REG_SZ /d "URL:thinkorswim URL" /f
C:\Windows\sysnative\reg.exe add HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\thinkorswim /v "URL Protocol" /t REG_SZ /f
C:\Windows\sysnative\reg.exe add HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\thinkorswim\shell\open\command /ve /t REG_SZ /d "\"C:\Program Files (x86)\thinkorswim\thinkorswim.exe\" AutologinLink %1" /f

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\reg.exe add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Version Vector" /v tossc /t REG_SZ /d 1.0 /f
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\reg.exe add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Version Vector" /v thinkorswim /t REG_SZ /d 1.0 /f
C:\Windows\sysnative\reg.exe add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Version Vector" /v tossc /t REG_SZ /d 1.0 /f
C:\Windows\sysnative\reg.exe add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Version Vector" /v thinkorswim /t REG_SZ /d 1.0 /f
```

You can then launch ToS with any of these:

```
# To launch from anywhere (if you alread have java installed or in ToS directory.)
javaw.exe -cp "C:\Program Files (x86)\thinkorswim\suit\1968.2.0\tos-suit-1968.2.0.jar" com.devexperts.jnlp.platform.impl.windows.WindowsSharedConfigurationLauncher SharedConfigurationLink A1PZUml

# To launch from ToS directory
.\thinkorswim.exe AutologinLink A1PZUml
.\thinkorswim.exe SharedConfigurationLink tossc:A1PZUml
```

Unfortunately none of these give any further info on how to get or see the *thinkscript*.

Comment: You can intercept web traffic using a tool like [Burp](https://portswigger.net/burp) or [ZAP](https://www.zaproxy.org/) if you can convince the app to route through a proxy.

Comment: If the web site triggers a locally installed program then there should be a process invocation which can be seen in Sysinternal Process Monitor. Disable file and registry events, you only need the process/thread events.

Comment: @Robert Yes, I did that and it only give me a DLL. Unfortunately I do not feel like trying to RE this code, as I don't think it should be necessary to accomplish what I am looking for.